# MySQL Composite Keys Integrity

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have this table

```
    CREATE TABLE `inventario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cla` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `lin` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `cal` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `uen` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `can` double NOT NULL,
  `fei` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fec` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `obs` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ppu` double NOT NULL,
  `pl1` double NOT NULL,
  `pl2` double NOT NULL,
  `pl3` double NOT NULL,
  `pl4` double NOT NULL,
  `prm` double NOT NULL,
  `pr1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pr2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mnm` double NOT NULL,
  `max` double NOT NULL,
  `dias` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `categoria` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`cla`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Id and cla are primary keys, but I need to keep the integrity and this structure allows duplicate "cla" values: F/e:

```
Id  |  Cla
01  | ADI001
02  | ADI001
```

And I need to avoid repeating the "cla" value in spite of the "id" value, how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique index on `cla`.  Add the line:

```
unique key cla
```